# Database of lots in Tokyo

Tags: data-request, geospatial, address, japan

I am looking for a dataset of all lots/addresses in the Tokyo Metropolis, or a dataset containing this information that I can process.

Japan has an open data portal, but most datasets are (logically) in Japanese, and none of the English-named ones appear to contain the relevant data:
http://www.data.go.jp/data/en/dataset

The 'Japan City Open Data Census' has 'no data' as to whether Tokyo provides this information:
http://jp-city.census.okfn.org/place/tokyo

Thanks for any help finding such a dataset, or even Japanese terms or resources to use to search for it.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't have direct experience with Japanese material, a quick search for Japan cadastral material reveals that this data might not exist in a digital form.

- "[The] lack of progress in surveying land in the Tokyo metropolitan area has become a serious problem" – Japan Times, "[Property borders: Where to draw the line](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/community/2015/01/02/how-tos/property-borders-where-to-draw-the-line/)", 2 January 2015
- [The Ministry of Land & Infrastructure](http://tochi.mlit.go.jp/english/generalpage/5604) has a map of land survey progress. The national average is 45%, the Tokyo region is labeled "less than 20%"

By the way, the best search term for this kind of data is "cadastre".

Answer (score 3):

In the first link in the original post, among the many datasets available in Japanese there is a resource from the Ministry of Land, Infrastructure and Transport that provides geocoordinates for addresses in most Tokyo wards and cities. The resource is

http://www.data.go.jp/data/en/dataset/mlit_20140919_3059

For example, there are around 178,000 building addresses for Setagaya ((世田谷区), population 900,000) which would seem comprehensive [as a single building can house anything from 1 to over 100 people], although I cannot be sure it is a complete list. I also note that some cities in the outskirts of Tokyo (e.g. Chofu 調布市) are not listed. The dataset for each city/ward within tokyo will give you four items of address data - machi (listed in japanese characters) = name of 'town' within the city/ward, Chome (i.e. district within the machi, usually a number from 1 to 12 listed here in Japanese characters), Gaiku (block number, as a number from 1 to about 50) and Bango (building number, again a number from 1 to about 50), as well as the geo-coordinates.

PS If anyone can give me a link to a similar dataset for Chofu, Tokyo (調布市) I would be very grateful!